# Dropdown menu is shown beneath other links

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles with a theme that I bought. Whenever hovering a `<a href>` that is above another `<a href>`, the dropdown-menu is shown beneath and should be shown above everything.

My first focus / attempt was to change the index, in this case increase the `z-index` of the `<div class="dropdown-menu">` to a number higher than the `<a href>` but that didn't work.

So, this is my HTML structure:

```
<li class="top_level dropdown">
    <a href="#">Category B</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu column1" style="">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <ul class="list-unstyled childs_1">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Category B - A</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Category B - B</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Category B - C</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the following image illustrates the problem **[in the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kg59Lpf4/)**:

[image]

Comment: Maybe also lower the z-index of the second navbar.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @clav you need to push the middle-separator to the left size, otherwise the categories won't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS is kind of a mess, but I found the problem! You're setting `z-index:20` to the main menu `li` elements. As they all have the same `z-index`, the ones that appear later in the markup are the ones that get on top when overlapping. If your menu was in one row, you wouldn't notice it.
The `z-index` of their children is not relevant in this context, only the parent. Just remove it:

[image: z-index fun]